# What could cause an intermittent flash of LED with a newly installed smart dimmer?

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch, smart-switch

I just installed a Lutron smart dimmer in place of an old dumb toggle switch that controls 4 dimmable LEDs. At max brightness, and with the brightness trimmed down a bit, I get an intermittent flicker (the set of lights go out) very quickly, just enough to be noticeable.

This happens maybe once an hour, sometimes more. It’s not really predictable. This only started happening with the smart dimmer not the original switch.

I have checked the connections many times, nothing is loose or exposed that shouldn’t be in the gang box. The LEDs are also compatible with the dimmer according to Lutron’s site.

What could be causing this? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Just wondering if something(fridge, furnace) in the the house is turning on, and the smart dimmer is picking up a voltage drop. Once an hour almost fits.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have seen it coincide with the ac but at other times it seems random. If it was something like this would it have happened with the old dumb switch too?

Comment: The smart dimmer uses electronics that might be more sensitive to minor voltage fluctuations than a dumb switch.  Might find a dumb dimmer would not be sensitive either.

Comment: Perhaps try poking Lutron tech support come Monday?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think I will call them again, they suggested I try incandescent bulbs (not an option for me) and trim the max brightness down a bit which didn’t work. I might try to see if a different brand of bulbs works and call them after that.

Comment: try different bulbs, especially newer model ones. there's a million (give or take) variables that affect compatibility between different dimmers and bulbs and wiring, so the easiest way to get a different result is to swap a whole variable, and the easiest to swap is almost always the bulbs.

Comment: @dandavis this was the answer. I should have known after trying multiple dimmers with the old bulbs, and having the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

It ended up being the LED bulb (cheap eco smart bulbs). I switched them out and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, phase-angle dimming of LEDs is a terrible hack, so compatibility issues are never a surprise, especially considering the price, formfactor, etc pressure placed on LED "bulbs".